# DataAnnotation Range validator not returning specified error message

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I have the following code in my metadata class for the Age field, which is typed as an int.

```
[Display(Name = "Age", Prompt = "Age")]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Age is required")]
[Range(16, 99, ErrorMessage = "Please specify an Age between 16 and 99")]
public int Age { get; set; }
```

In my view I have the field defined as:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age, new { @class = "form-control numeric", @placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Age), @type = "number", @min = "16", @max = "99", @maxlength = "2" })
```

In the form, the HTML is rendered as such:

```
<input name="Age" class="form-control numeric" id="Age" type="number" maxlength="2" min="16" max="99" placeholder="Age" value="" data-val-required="Age is required" data-val-number="The field Age must be a number." data-val="true" data-val-range-min="16" data-val-range-max="99" data-val-range="Please specify an Age between 16 and 99">
```

Yet the error message that is returned is:

```
Please enter a value greater than or equal to 16.
```

Has anyone else encountered this error before?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Some chump downvotes me and doesn't have the stones to post a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Apparently, this happens when the field is defined as a number as opposed to a text field.

I changed:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age, new { @class = "form-control numeric", @placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Age), @type = "number", @min = "16", @max = "99", @maxlength = "2" })
```

to:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age, new { @class = "form-control numeric", @placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Age), @maxlength = "2" })
```

and now it works like a champ.